# ssh to run shell script on remote machine and then copy the output to local machine

Tags: shell, ssh, plink

I am using `plink` to execute the shell script on the remote `MachineB`. And shell script is there on the `MachineA(Windows Box)`.

```
C:\PLINK>plink uname@MachineB -m test.sh 
Using keyboard-interactive authentication. 
Password: 
Using keyboard-interactive authentication. 
Your Kerberos password will expire in 73 days.
```

And that shell script generates the output in a `text file(aa.txt)` on MachineB and that gets stored in `/export/home/uname/aa.txt`

**So my question is-** Is there any way that I can copy the `aa.txt file` from `MachineB` to `MachineA` as soon the script has completed all its task using the `ssh`. Or we need to put all these things in Windows Batch file?

So Problem Statement is like this-

1. Execute the shell script on `MachineB` from `MachineA`.
2. Then wait for the shell script to complete its task, in my case it will write the output to a text file.
3. And after the shell script has completed all its task means it finished writing everything to a txt file, then copy that txt file to `MachineA` from `MachineB`

Any suggestions will be appreciated on how I can achieve the above scenario?

**Update:-**

So Suppose if this is the content in test.sh shell script file and also after adding pscp at the end of script, then it should be like this?

```
#!/bin/bash 
export HIVE_OPTS="$HIVE_OPTS -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology" 
hive -S -e 'SELECT count(*) from testingtable2' > aa.txt 
pscp uname@MachineB:/export/home/uname/aa.txt c:\documents\foo.txt
```

So I am executing a hive query in the above script and whose output is getting stored in `aa.txt` file and as soon as the query is completed and output is stored in `aa.txt` file, it will go to `fourth line of pscp` which will transfer aa.txt file to my local windows machine inside documents folder. Am I right? This will be the whole process?

And if the above process is right as far as I understood, then I can simply go to windows cmd prompt, and do like below and it will do the exact same process. Right?

```
C:\PLINK>plink uname@MachineB -m test.sh 
Using keyboard-interactive authentication. 
Password: 
Using keyboard-interactive authentication. 
Your Kerberos password will expire in 73 days.
```

**Updated Again:-**

So I need to create a bat file, and suppose this is the below `test.bat` file, so content should be like this in that `test.bat` file-

```
plink uname@MachineB -m test.sh 
pscp  uname@MachineB:/export/home/uname/aa.txt c:\documents\foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scp` to download the file after execution. If you setup [winsshd](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) on your windows machine and `append` a copy command in the test.sh file:

```
scp /export/home/uname/aa.txt user@windowsmachine.com:/homedir
```

The file will be transferred after completion.

Similarly, you can use a windows scp client like [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) on your windows machine, you can pull the file from the linux machine:

```
pscp uname@MachineB:/export/home/uname/aa.txt c:\documents\foo.txt
```

So on windows machine, have a batch script:

```
plink uname@MachineB -m test.sh 
pscp  uname@MachineB:/export/home/uname/aa.txt c:\documents\foo.txt
```

Comment: Thanks perreal for the solution, Is there any way I can put all these things in one file instead of executing all these things sequentially? So that whenever I want to do these things, I should run one file and that will do all the required things for me?

Comment: I have updated the question by adding the pscp line into my test.sh file, Can you take a look whether I understood exactly as said by you? And it will do the exact same process as I think currently?

Comment: Create a batch file in Windows with 2 commands: 1) plink 2) pscp. What you are trying to do above is not totally correct. If you want to send the file from linux to windows then you need to specify the address of the windows machine and setup a ssh server on windows.

Comment: Ok.. That makes sense to me. So How I can create a batch file in windows with those two commands? Can you give me any suggestions as I am new to all these things. It will be of great help to me.

Comment: I updated the question again by posting what I understood from you, Can you take a look again and let me know it looks good to you as far as I understand from your comment. And is there any change required in that?

Comment: And I have one more doubt on that, So in that test.bat file, it will execute the first line, and after the first line has been executed and finished writing the output to text file, then it will go to the second line and copy that text file from unix to windows machine right?

Comment: correct, it will copy the file after the completion of `test.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what has already been said, I am running something very similar and use the following format (from a batch script):

plink -ssh user@ -pw password -m yourScript.sh

pscp -sftp -pw password user@IP-Address:/path/to/remote/file C:\path\to\local\save\directory

That second command is on one line, but it might not render like that on here. Of course, replace IP-Address, user, and password with the appropriate values for your login :-)

Hope that helps!

EDIT - Sorry, just realized this *EXACT* answer was already given. Kudos!